# Graph API for accessing teams and team's groups to pull documents

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-teams

I am working on asset management system in which my application needs to pull specific documents of all the employees being stored by them on teams or any teams group.
Using graph API or any other medium, how can I achieve the same. Any suggestions or pointers will be helpful to start with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Teams has a associated Group.

So you need to get the list of all the Teams first through ([reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/teams-list-all-teams?context=graph%2Fapi%2F1.0&view=graph-rest-1.0#get-a-list-of-groups-using-beta-apis)):

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/groups?$filter=resourceProvisioningOptions/Any(x:x eq 'Team')
```

Then you can traverse this list to get the Group (Teams) id.

Get the channels in an Teams like this ([reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/channel-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)):

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teams/{Group id}/channels
```

Record the channels' name.

Now use this call to get the files stored in a Teams channel ([reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-list-children?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#list-children-of-a-driveitem-with-a-known-path)):

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/{Group id}/drive/root:/{channel name}:/children
```

You need to implement multiple loops to get all the files stored in Teams.

**UPDATE:**

Using the following request to list the items in the Teams:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/{Group id}/drive/root/children
```

You can get the item id of **General folder** from the response.

Then you can get the files under **General folder** through:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/{Group id}/drive/items/{item id}/children
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestions. Much appreciated. I will try to implement and come back on this.

Comment: To add more clarity on the requirement, in my case,  there are roughly 15k employees and if any of the users upload the "abc.pptx" document on teams then it should be available on the application in real time and if someone deletes from teams, it should be deleted from the application as well. Basically both should be in sync with each other.

Comment: If I use this iteration process to achieve the same, it would not be real time, there will always be a time gap. Just wondering, is there any notification service available in teams, which confirms the document uploaded/deleted on teams/channels/tabs and by whom. So that only specific document can be read instead of iterating all the documents. Or any other way out.

Comment: See [Set up notifications for changes in user data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/webhooks). The related call is [Create subscription](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/subscription-post-subscriptions?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http). Note that the file is stored in SharePoint. So you should create subscription for **driveItem (OneDrive for Business)** as Supported resources.

Comment: Thanks, i will have a look into this and confirm.

Comment: @TarunNarang Any updates? If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer. This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry @AllenWu, I did not get a chance to work on this and got involved in some other activities. I will definitely post my answer before end of this month. Thanks

Comment: @TarunNarang Sure. Keep posted:)

Comment: I worked on this and got an error while reading the files from drive. I tried other ways too but got stuck to retrieve the Items-Id.  The results of the commands executed are shared in the document - [Document Link - Commands Executed](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1_RpKXJfHAzdlObR7BfqPSIAsLG9S6JJCcc0LmbxzowM/edit?usp=sharing).

Comment: @TarunNarang It's strange. The requests look OK. I'll provide the way which uses item-id. See my update in answer.

Comment: Yes, its really strange. Executing this command - https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/{Group id}/drive/root/children returned **"Items Not Found". **  Commands results are added in the document at the end section - [Updated Commands Executed Document](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1_RpKXJfHAzdlObR7BfqPSIAsLG9S6JJCcc0LmbxzowM/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: @TarunNarang The request in your link is `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/5c334f32-405c-4d33-bf02-e16725e0fd13/drive/root:/General:/children`. But in the comment you said `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups{Group id}/drive/root/children`. Can you check it?

Comment: My mistake, I mentioned wrong URL in the comment section, `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/5c334f32-405c-4d33-bf02-e16725e0fd13/drive/root:/General:/children`. This is the same URL I executed to retrieve the results and shared in the link. And this did not return any results. And at the same time if you see the result of this query `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teams/5c334f32-405c-4d33-bf02-e16725e0fd13/channels/19:0f17d24b4dc2416bb9336067d52e0a58@thread.tacv2/filesFolder` in the document link, it shows the childCount as 3

Comment: @TarunNarang I have seen that. So I updated my answer to provide a way which uses item id. Did you try it?

Comment: Thanks, Yes, I did. It did not return any items- `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/5c334f32-405c-4d33-bf02-e16725e0fd13/drive/root/children - {
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#groups('5c334f32-405c-4d33-bf02-e16725e0fd13')/drive/root/children",
    "value": []
}`

Comment: @TarunNarang Check if the files exist in SharePoint. See https://i.stack.imgur.com/JNmYG.png

Comment: Yes the images exist on sharepoint. [Section - Update-2](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1_RpKXJfHAzdlObR7BfqPSIAsLG9S6JJCcc0LmbxzowM/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: @TarunNarang The user account you are using to call Microsoft Graph API is owner or member of this group? Or is it a group admin account?

Comment: The user account of Microsoft Graph API is owner of the group. However, while looking for the permissions I found, the user account I am using to connect Microsoft Graph API did not have permission on "Files.ReadAll". The moment I consent on this, it started reading the files. Thank You!! so much Allen. Much appreciated. I will further test for user notification changes.

Comment: @TarunNarang Glad to know that. If there is any further concern, you can post it here. If my answer is helpful, you could mark it as accepted. Thank you.